# C# Web Application memory overflow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, memory-management

C# Web Application memory overhead .. this is happen as follows

1-I have web application on server called xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
the web application performance is so bad CPU memory and usage get overflow..

2-I moved the web application to another IIS on to another machine it works fine without any leaks and no overhead memory.

and performance is pretty good.

what maybe cause this problem ? if the hard has bad sector may affect this or what also i have used Microsoft tool called Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2 [Debug Diagnostic](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798) but no luck ?

Comment: If possible use a profiler or intellitrace to try and figure out why the 1st machine is behaving this badly. Try to find the variables in the 2 scenario's that differ.

Comment: can you provide me with more details please about profiler and intellitrace ??

Comment: There are many profilers. Bottom line it's a tool that will help you identify hotspots/problem area's in your environment. JetBrains* is one that pops to mind, but there are many out there. *http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/